# Orion VM rebooting

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I installed and started Orion Context Broker (version 2.2.0) on Centos 7 OS with these commands:

```
$ sudo wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d/ https://nexus.lab.fiware.org/repository/raw/public/repositories/el/7/x86_64/fiware-release.repo
$ sudo yum -y install contextBroker
$ sudo service contextBroker start
```

When I reboot the Centos VM, the Orion doesn't restart automatically and neither by using command script.
The workaround is to remove and reinstall it.
Is my installation procedure correct?
Thank you for your support.

Comment: "...neither by using command script"... Can you edit your question post to include how exactly are you running that script, please? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your replay. These are my steps after installation procedure:
sudo service contextBroker start, included also sudo chkconfig contextBroker on and selinux disabled. After reboot Orion doesn't restart anymore.

Comment: What `chkconfig --list | grep contextBroker` shows *before* and *after* the reboot?